# is Photron Stedy Pro 560 compatible with canon 600d

Tags: tripod, canon-600d, tripod-heads

I want to know that is [Photron Stedy Pro 560](http://www.flipkart.com/photron-stedy-pro-560/p/itmdsxdv5vkg8cxt?pid=ACCDSXDQAJVZ58GB&offer=DOTDOnCamera_Nov23.&icmpid=hp_dotd_4_DOTDOnCamera_Nov23) compatible with canon 600D. It's head will be set with 600D?

Comment: Although it's not literally the same question, this is covered by what I've linked above. Fortunately, we don't need to check for every tripod and camera combination.